# converting data from pdf to numeric in R

Tags: r

I am new to "R", still learning basics..

In one situation, I got some population data from a website, in xls format.
When I tried to read that (using read.xls from gdata package), data came in R (a data frame). However, everything is character, which is fine so far.

After some cleansing of unnecessary rows and columns etc, I am trying to convert the numbers (present as characters) into numeric values wherein I am facing strange behaviour...

My data elements look like this (some sample here)

```
> class(males1)
[1] "factor"

> males1[1]
[1] 6,665,561
```

males1 is supposed to contain n rows, with one element each, the number of males per state. When I am applying as.numeric on the values, its actually giving me back a sum of digits

```
> as.numeric(males1[1])
[1] 35
```

When I convert that males1 into a vector, I get back a different error

```
> vv=as.vector(males1)
> vv[1]
[1] "6,665,561"
> as.numeric(vv[1])
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

I am sure, I am missing on something really basic..

help please...

Comment: What number does `","` represent? Answer: it doesn't represent a number, so you need to remove it before you can convert the factor/character to a number: `as.numeric(gsub(",","",levels(males1)))[males1]`

Comment: I think it's just your unluck that `35 == 6+6+6+5+5+6+1` , making you think you're getting a sum of digits.  Are you seeing a sum of digits for other cases as well?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your reading in a `csv` that has commas instead of decimals or that seperates big numbers?

because of the commas:

```
> males1[1]
[1] 6,665,561 # is this meant to be 6665561 ?
```

is a factor.  When you do `as.numeric` to a factor you will get a number but it is just the number of the factor in the order of the levels.

```
   x <- c("a","b","c")
   x <- as.factor(x)
   as.numeric(x)
   #[1] 1 2 3
```

Is it possible you want remove them with `?gsub` or use `dec="."` in your read.csv?

Comment: I am reading a xls file. The commas appear like the million separator. This example value is actually 6665561 as a numeric. Whats the right way to convert this number as a proper numeric value ?

Comment: Cue up my favorite http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f     `as.numeric(as.character(some_factor))`  It's one of the nastier stumbling blocks in `R` .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: that's not the only problem. You also have to remove the commas.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Sorry, you're absolutely correct.  You gotta do something like `scan(stuff, dec=',')`